# Azure Resource Manager storage - can I delete a VHD file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure

I've recently been learning Azure Resource Manager template based deployment, and as a result I am deploying and removing a lot of VMs as I refine my ResourceManager templates. I have made a PowerShell script to delete a given VM,LoadBalancer,PublicIPAddress,NetworkInterface,etc but I can't find an equivalent cmdlet for removing a VHD / blob / from an AzureRM Storage account.

**Is there an AzureRM PowerShell way to delete a VHD file stored in an Azure ResourceManager Storage account?** Or is this yet to be implemented? If not, are there any command line alternatives such as Azure CLI or a workaround?

I've looked at:

```
Get-Command -Module AzureRM.Storage
```

This shows:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                                     
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                                     
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmStorageAccount                          1.1.3      AzureRm.Storage                                                                            
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey                       1.1.3      AzureRm.Storage                                                                            
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability          1.1.3      AzureRm.Storage                                                                            
Cmdlet          Get-AzureRmStorageUsage                            1.1.3      AzureRm.Storage                                                                            
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmStorageAccount                          1.1.3      AzureRm.Storage                                                                            
Cmdlet          New-AzureRmStorageAccountKey                       1.1.3      AzureRm.Storage                                                                            
Cmdlet          Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount                       1.1.3      AzureRm.Storage                                                                            
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount                   1.1.3      AzureRm.Storage                                                                            
Cmdlet          Set-AzureRmStorageAccount                          1.1.3      AzureRm.Storage
```

... which doesn't have what I want. The closest would be adding and removing an entire storage account, but since I'm deploying from a custom template I believe I am limited to storing the VM VHD in the same storage account as the template (please correct me if I'm wrong). By contrast, the Azure.Storage module has *StorageFile/Blob/Container cmdlets. Given I see classic Azure cmdlets that sound like what I want, but no AzureRM equivalents, I suspect the answer is "no" for the moment.

For reference, I'm running Windows 10, and have installed the latest AzureRM PowerShell module from the PowerShell Gallery within the past couple of weeks (AzureRM Module 1.6.0, AzureRM.Storage 1.1.3)

Comment: This was asked on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204554/removing-vhds-from-azure-resource-manager-after-removing-vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the Context to the Remove-AzureStorageBlob.

```
$RGName = "stlvm"
$SAName = "stlvmstorage"
$ConName = "testcontainer"
$BlobName = "Test02.txt"
$Keylist = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $RGName -StorageAccountName $SAName
$Key = $Keylist[0].Value
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SAName -StorageAccountKey $Key
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx | select Name
Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ConName -Blob $BlobName -Context $Ctx
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx | select Name
```

I've tested it on my lab server. It works for me.

[image: Azure]

Comment: Right on, that did the trick. Having never used the old "ASM" Azure Cmdlets much, I didn't realize to what extent they could interoperate. This also is a better and more complete answer than the one linked in a comment. Thanks!